# Angular returning promise object from service. Trying to access value to change ng-if directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, promise

I've seen similar issues to the one but hoping someone can give me some help.

I'm trying to verify that a user is logged in and modify the html for a sign in or log out button.

```
this.getUser = function(){
 return $http.get('/api/user');
};
```

service

```
vm.user = function() { 
  dataService.getUser().then(function(res){
    if(res.data.userId.length){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

controller

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-hide='vm.user()'>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/api/signin">Sign in</a>
</li>
```

I've tried different variations of this to no avail. I'm either returning a promise object or not able to use the variable outside of promise. Thanks

Comment: you need to return `dataService.getUser().then..` also like `return dataService.getUser().then...`

Answer (score 1):

Just use variable instead watching entire function in ng-hide directive. Please find the code snippet.

Controller File:

```
vm.flags = {};
vm.user = function() { 
  dataService.getUser().then(function(res){
    if(res.data.userId.length){
      vm.flags.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    }else{
      vm.flags.isUserLoggedIn = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Html File

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-hide='vm.flags.isUserLoggedIn'>
        <a class="nav-link" href="/api/signin">Sign in</a>
</li>
```